# new Socket hangs the application

Tags: java, sockets

My `JFrame` just hangs up (freezes) when I'm trying to create a new `Socket`. The very same code (not same .java file, but same lines of code) works on a computer next to me.

**Any idea why the code freezes?**

*try #1*

```
private Socket socket;
public void connect( String ip, int port ) {    
    try {
        System.out.println( ip + " " + port );  //just to show the arguments doesn't seem to be the issue.
        socket = new Socket(ip,port);
        System.out.println(".");    

    } catch (IOException e) {System.out.println(e);}    
}
```

Output in console (*xxx = digets*). As you can see, "." is never printed.

> 192.*xxx*.*xxx*.53 1494

Nor does this work (frame 'freeze' and same output).

*try #2*

```
public void connect( String ip, int port ) {
    try {
        System.out.println( ip + " " + port );
        socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ip,port), 5000);
        System.out.println(".");

    } catch (IOException e) {System.out.println(e);}    
}
```

> 192.*xxx*.*xxx*.53 1494

Comment: check firewall, strace, netstat.

Answer (score 3):

You're running that code in the Swing Event Dispatch Thread. This is the thread that performs things like processing events in listeners, and performs painting.

It hangs because the Socket is trying to connect, and during that time there can be no event handling or painting since the thread is busy (trying to connect).

Socket connection (and reading/writing) needs to happen in its own thread, so as not to block the EDT.

Comment: Cheers, running it on its own thread removed the 'freeze' but the socket still never creates.

Answer (score 2):

You probably wanna specify a max duration, something like a firewall could block your socket from connecting. take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#connect-java.net.SocketAddress-int-

also, as `@user11091841` mentioned, run it in a different thread

Comment: hm, doesn't try #2 specifies max duration?

Comment: it does yes (i read over that, sorry), but both don't run on a different thread, they should. And are you sure that the server reacts?

Comment: Running it on its own thread removed the 'freeze'! but the socket still never creates. Server workes fine! (same output to console as seen above)

Comment: are you sure the point you're connecting to actually accepts you?, have you tried debugging it

Comment: @Strazan are you connecting to a computer on the same network, as you're using an internal IP